# NTP not updating back to system time in macOS

Tags: macos, ntp

In macOS 10.12.6 , I am trying to forward the clock using the *date* command.

E.g.: today's date is 25-09-2017 and I am setting it to 27-09-2017. But using ntp I am unable to revert my system time back to 25-09-2017.

I have "time.asia.apple.com" set in /etc/ntp.conf.

When I try to issue the command

```
sudo killall -9 ntpd; sudo ntpdate "time.asia.apple.com"
```

I am getting the following output:

> 27 Sep 20:25:36 ntpdate[5085]: no server suitable for synchronization found

I am not sure why my system time is not moving back to 25th of Sep.

I even tried it with "time1.google.com" . The clock is still not returning back to today's date.

Answer (score 1):

"no server suitable for synchronization found" indicates that the time server *time.asia.apple.com* can't be found or in-bound ntp traffic is not allowed at some perimeter.

Your host either has no proper Internet connection or DNS resolution is wonky.

However, you can try to check your Internet connection (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`), repair the Internet if necessary (e.g. `repair Internet local|global all`) and repeat your *ntpdate* command or use one of the various IP addresses of time.asia.apple.com (17.253.52.125, 17.253.54.253, 17.253.54.125) directly:

```
sudo ntpdate 17.253.54.125
```

If the last command works DNS resolution is broken.

---

`repair Internet local|global all` shouldn't be taken literally.

Comment: i checked the internet connection. i am able to surf internet and ping 8.8.8.8 is working as well.

Comment: i am able to ping both via IP and time.apple.com or other ntp servers like time1.google.com. Still when i issue ntp command, i get the synchronization error.

Comment: Checked firewall as well. its not blocking the ports. Any other thing that needs to be checked ?

Comment: yes.. we have a ntp server running. and we have synced with the ntp server before as well. but now , its not working

Comment: is there any other way we can restore back the system time apart from ntp

Comment: @srinath I asked for a ntp server set up on your Mac locally. A second command to set the time is `sudo sntp -a 17.253.54.125`.

Comment: i need to do it in python since this is part of automation. its not a one time setup. same would be running in n number of virtual machines which are the fresh images.

Comment: let me try with the sntp command and get back to you

Comment: @srinath Please add any details (Python/VM/automation) to your question. Is your macOS 10.12.6 host running in a VM?